# For iOS, is it possible to have a Toast message that can display on top of system app Settings?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xamarin

I have a button in my app that brings up the system app settings UI. Instructions are given around the button.

I want to provide further instructions to the user via a toast message after the settings page shows up so they know exactly what to do. It's not a super intuitive setting, related to notification style, and such instructions would be a lot clearer when the user is actually on the settings page.

In Android, this is easily done via `toast.makeText().show()`. The resulting toast would have no problem going on top of the system settings UI.

In iOS though, I've looked up several guides, mostly using the `UIView` animation. The problem is, the resulting toast window seems to only work inside the app itself. It cannot go on top of the system settings UI.

Is what I want to achieve technically possible in iOS?

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Comment: I think it's not possible. Rather you can show an UIAlertController or custom popup view and show the instruction there. Then when user tap the yes/ok button of the alertController, take them to system setting app.

Comment: @talha_kuet Yeah that's what I already did. Unfortunately this particular setting requires 2 more level of clicks inside the settings, and it'd be a lot clearer if the instructions are actually shown on the settings page itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You are sandboxed; Settings is a different app and you cannot impose anything on to its interface.

Comment: That's unfortunate. We obviously don't want to interfere with other apps. I wish they'd expose a system level display like Android's toast . Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Yeah, our app has the same issue. We send you off to system settings where you have to do something really confusing.